# Gnuplot can't read the .dat file

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I've created a file in notepad and saved it as ANSI and .dat file. The file structure looks like:

```
2019 371320
2018 352137
2017 323201
2016 302271
2015 291377
2014 282730
2013 273467
2012 257093
2011 244541
2010 223488
2009 216949
2008 197778
(...)
```

Then gnuplot terminal being opened I set the settings I want to and after the `plot "dates1.dat" using 2:xticlabels(1) with boxes lt rgb "#406090"` an error pops up:

```
Warning! Cannot find or open file "dates1.dat"
         No data in plot
```

Whole settings:

```
# Output to PNG, with Verdana 8pt font
set terminal pngcairo nocrop enhanced font "verdana,8" size 640,300

# Don't show the legend in the chart
set nokey 

# Thinner, filled bars
set boxwidth 0.4
set style fill solid 1.00 

# Set a title and Y label. The X label is obviously months, so we don't set it.
set title "Number of registrations per month" font ",14" tc rgb "#606060"
set ylabel "Registrations (thousands)"

# Rotate X labels and get rid of the small stripes at the top (nomirror)
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45

# Show human-readable Y-axis. E.g. "100 k" instead of 100000.
set format y '%.0s %c'

# Replace small stripes on the Y-axis with a horizontal gridlines
set tic scale 0
set grid ytics lc rgb "#505050"

# Remove border around chart
unset border

# Manual set the Y-axis range
set yrange [100000 to 300000]

set output "6.png"
plot "dates1.dat" using 2:xticlabels(1) with boxes lt rgb "#406090"
```

The dates1.dat file is full of data as I showed before. Any thoughts on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gnuplot console type `pwd` which will print the current working directory. Is your file located in this directory? If not either give the full path, e.g.

```
plot 'C:/myDir/subDir/dates1.dat' ...
```

or change the working directory with `cd`. Check `help pwd` and `help cd`.